# Change iframe youtube src with jquery - IE8 Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, twitter-bootstrap, custom-data-attribute

I am using the following code to load different youtube videos into a Twitter Bootstrap modal. Why is it that IE8 is the only browser that does not load the youtube video? It just displays a black div where the video would normally show up. There are more videos to be uploaded and a lot of additional scripts on the page I am working on, so I am trying to keep this as flexible and lightweight as possible. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks! **jsfiddle at bottom.**

```
<div id="Videos">
    <a data-source="http://www.youtube.com/embed/z4Ezruu1oeQ" href="#" class="videoThumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100&text=Video%20Thumbnail%20One"></a>

    <a data-source="http://www.youtube.com/embed/3tYrd4tPVXs" href="#" class="videoThumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100&text=Video%20Thumbnail%20Two"></a>

</div>


<div id="videoModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="video-container">
            <iframe width="520" height="390" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Javascript:

```
$('.videoThumbnail').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var src = $(this).data('source');
    $('#videoModal').modal('show');
    $('#videoModal iframe').attr('src', src);
});

$('#videoModal button').click(function () {
    $('#videoModal iframe').removeAttr('src');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/curly33/LTxm7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest letting the html do the work.

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/z4Ezruu1oeQ" target="videoIframe" class="videoThumbnail">
```

and

```
<iframe name="videoIframe" width="520" height="390" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

small modification to js:

```
$('.videoThumbnail').click(function(e) {
    $('#videoModal').modal('show');
});
$('#videoModal button').click(function () {
    $('#videoModal iframe').removeAttr('src');
    // ^^ is this really needed? ^^
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LTxm7/3/

Comment: That woud do it! Thanks. I was using the bottom part of the script to make the video stop playing when the closed button was clicked. I'll have to figure out another way to make it stop playing now.

Comment: That's why i left it in, i wasn't sure. Leaving it in should continue to do what it was previously doing.

Comment: For anyone else who has this problem, I changed the bottom code to this 
`$('#videoModal').on('hide', function () {
$('#videoModal iframe').removeAttr('src');
});` 
so that the video will stop playing however the modal is closed